# XML file to set and change div colors

Tags: php, css, xml

The main page I'm working with uses php and has a number of divs on it.  I need to set up an external XML file that will contain "div1" "color1" through "div4 "color4" (then I'll need to use a button to read the xml data and "use it to change the colors" of those 4 divs on the main page).  I've gone through the xml tutorials on w3schools with a fine tooth comb and can't for the life of me figure out how to write the xml code to define the colors for the divs.  If I can get that first part(!) then I should be able to figure out how to write a function to do the rest.  If anyone can help, I would be so extremely grateful.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div id = "div1">
            <p>This will be a mini sidebar </p>
    </div>

    <div id = "div2">

    </div>

    <div id = "div3">

    </div>

    <div id = "div4">

    </div>
```

The initial background colors are set with a CSS external file:

```
#div1 {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}

#div2 {

    background-color:pink;
    height:30px;
    width:50px;
    float:right;
    padding:5px; 
}

#div3 {

    background-color:orange;
    height:200px;
    width:70px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}

#div4 {

    background-color:blue;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    padding:5px; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful, if you at least post some code, like the PHP / HTML structure you have and the structure of the proposed XML file

Comment: Here is my HTML code::  <div id = "div1">
                <p>We're starting to divvy things up :) </p>
        </div>
        
        <div id = "div2">
                
        </div>
        
        <div id = "div3">
                
        </div>
        
        <div id = "div4">
                
        </div>